# Service Worker sync event not firing

Tags: promise, synchronization, indexeddb, service-worker-events

I'm persisting a review posted offline in the indexedDB and registering a sync with the service worker, but once back online, the sync is not firing unless I post a new review. 
After some research I think it happens due to the chained promises in the event.waitUntil function. Perhaps someone can guide me in the right direction:

```
self.addEventListener('sync', event => {
  if (event.tag == 'outbox') {
    event.waitUntil(
      postReview()
    ).catch(err => {
      if (event.lastChance) {
        self.registration.showNotification('Failed');
      }
      throw err;
    });
  }
});



postReview = () => {
  DBHelper.openDB()
    .then(db => {
      const tx = db.transaction(['outbox'], 'readonly');
      const store = tx.objectStore('outbox');
      return store.getAll();
    })
    .then(reviews => {
      return Promise.all(
        reviews.map(review => {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('restaurant_id', review.restaurant_id);
          formData.append('name', review.name);
          formData.append('rating', review.rating);
          if (review.comments.value) {
            formData.append('comments', review.comments);
          }
          return fetch(`${DBHelper.REVIEWS_URL}/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
          }).then(data => {
            if (data) {
              return DBHelper.openDB().then(db => {
                const tx = db.transaction('outbox', 'readwrite');
                const store = tx.objectStore('outbox');
                return store.delete(review.id);
              });
            }
          }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
        })
      );
    });
};
```

At all times I'm getting

```
Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined at self.addEventListener.event (sw.js:97)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like waitUntil expects a promise argument, but you are calling a function that returns undefined, not a promise. Try returning a promise from postReview. When using fat arrow syntax, the implicit return only occurs when not using the block `{}` syntax. So you must explicitly return.

Comment: @Andrey Kolybelnikov, In addition to returning, there's a bunch of other stuff to address in `postReview()`: 
(1) it seems unlikely that `db.transaction(['outbox'] ...)` and `db.transaction('outbox' ...)` are both correct;
(2) the pattern can be adjusted to allow the outer `db` connection to be reused in the inner scope;
(2) don't forget to dispose of your `db` connection (under sucess and error conditions);
(4) don't forget to re-throw the caught `err`, otherwise it won't propagate upwards to the caller.

Comment: @Josh, returning explicitly doesn't change the behavior, the sync is still not firing. Strangely, it all goes well when online: I get the same undefined error in the console, but a post goes through the chain and it posted. Also, the previously saved posts are posted and the IndexedDB is emptied.